# Stuck on assignment that uses an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing an assignment where I make an object that is called BoxOfTruffles it holds a reference to an array of Strings. In this class, a string in this array represents a truffle in the box.

Here is the assignment: http://webpages.sou.edu/~nordquip/cs256/labs/l8/doc/BoxOfTruffles.html

Here is my code..

My question is how do I implement the add method?

```
public class BoxOfTruffles
extends java.lang.Object
{
    private String[] si;

    public BoxOfTruffles(int len)
    {
        si = new String[len];
    }
    public boolean add(java.lang.String t)
    {
        t = IO.readString("Enter flavor > ");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: You don't have to add the extension to the Object class. It does it automatically.

Comment: Also writing `java.lang` is just.. weird

Comment: @Kade Lewis We do not know how to add your Truffles as well, because you didn't tell us how.

Answer (score 1):

So, assignment to an array in Java is simple:

```
array[location] = value;
```

where "array" is the name of the array, "location" is an int representing the position (with 0 as the first position) and "value" as the value to be inserted.

One thing to remember is that arrays have a fixed size when they're created. If you try to put something in an index greater than the size of the array, you get an exception - so you need to design your code to avoid this. If you want to avoid that, there are other data structures (such as Lists, including ArrayLists) that have variable size - the JVM will re-size them as necessary, to store whatever you add.

For this assignment, it looks like you need to have a way to find (or remember) the next "open" position in your array. You can do this either by keeping track of what that is and updating it when it changes (i.e., when you insert a truffle), or by re-calculating it each time, by searching for the first null value in the array.

Comment: So to keep an "open" position should I set the location to a variable and increment it?

Comment: Yeah - keep track of the first open position in your array.